Unit testing a stream being retried
I've written a stream that calls the foobarMethod, potentially triggering the mono of a SocketTimeoutException. I want this method to retry 2 times. Manually, this code works but in the junit test I can't get it to retry. Is this because of an environment issue with unit tests or have I dont the tests wrong? Any help gratefully received. Thanks.
public void foobarServiceMethod() {
   foobarClient.foobarMethod(foobarParameter)
            .onErrorMap(ex -> {
                log.error("Code has failed");
                if (ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    return new SocketTimeoutException("");
                } else {
                    return ex;
                }
            })
            .retryWhen(
                    Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                            .filter(SocketTimeoutException.class::isInstance))
            .subscribe(foobarResponse -> handleFoobarResoponse(foobarResponse));

@Test
void foobarRest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) throws SocketTimeoutException, InterruptedException {
    foobarParameter = "test";
    when(foobarClient.foobarMethod(any()))
            .thenReturn(Mono.error(new SocketTimeoutException("First timeout")))
            .thenReturn(Mono.error(new SocketTimeoutException("First timeout")));

    foobarMethod(foobarParameter);

    assertEquals(2, capturedOutputSplit.contains("Code has failed");
}


For running tests on reactive you have to use reactor-test dependency, instead of executing separately reactive code with subscribe, you have to call it with StepVerifier.create(<your publisher>). more details can be found here
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>

public Mono<Foo> foobarServiceMethod() {//return Mono/Flux dependig of result of foobarClient.foobarMethod
   return foobarClient.foobarMethod(foobarParameter)
            .onErrorMap(ex -> {
                log.error("Code has failed");
                if (ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    return new SocketTimeoutException("");
                } else {
                    return ex;
                }
            })
            .retryWhen(
                    Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                            .filter(SocketTimeoutException.class::isInstance));

@Test
void foobarRest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) throws SocketTimeoutException, InterruptedException {
    foobarParameter = "test";
    when(foobarClient.foobarMethod(any()))
            .thenReturn(Mono.error(new SocketTimeoutException("First timeout")))
            .thenReturn(Mono.error(new SocketTimeoutException("First timeout")));

    StepVerifier.create(foobarMethod(foobarParameter))
    .expectErrorSatisfies(..)// error verify logic
    //.expectNextMatches(...) OR check on success
     .expectComplete()
    .verify();
}

